# How to make combo box accept value from keyboard

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have a combo box wherein I am feeding in items in drop down box. Apart from this I also want my combo box to accept the values I feed from my keyboard. When I write anything in the combo box then I get this exception message:

> InvalidArgument=Value of '-1' is not valid for 'index'.
>   Parameter name: index

It should display a list of items in list box from the index I gave in combo box 1 to combo box 2.

How to do this?

Comment: yea..it is editable already.Just that whenever i write something i get exception

Answer (score 1):

The combobox has a DropDownStyle property. This property change the behaviour of the combbox in runtime. Check if you can set a value in this property that matches the behaviour that you want.

Other option could be using an  AutoComplete TextBox/Combobox. Here is a link with info about how to do it.[LINK](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/AutoCompletion02012006113508AM/AutoCompletion.aspx). It is preyty easy.

Comment: there is none. i tried simple, dropdown and dropdownlist. none working. currently i am using dropdown.

Comment: I dont need auto complete. I need to input my own values. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For this to happen, you need to capture the TextChanged event of the combo box and write the appropriate event handling code to populate the second list box.